# Update values in a dataframe at every nth value with a group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe for which i would like to populate with some values in 'snail_chart_dates' without using a loop.

The values I would like are the first 'value_date' and the last 'value_date' and the middle 'value_date' grouped by code_id

I think this could be done maybe with a combination of `.iloc[0]` and `.iloc[-1]` but I have no idea how to apply this to a `groupby` or how to get the middle

**Example trimmed data frame - other one is much longer**

[image]

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np 

    returns = pd.DataFrame({
            'value_date' : ['2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31','2018-04-30', '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30', 
                            '2018-01-31', '2018-02-28', '2018-03-31','2018-04-30', '2018-05-31', '2018-06-30'],
            'code_id' :  ['AUD','AUD','AUD','AUD','AUD','AUD', 
                          'USD','USD','USD','USD','USD','USD'],
            'gross_return': [.01, .02, .03, -.4, -.06, -.02, 
                             .06, .8, .9, .4, -1.06, .03],
            'bm_return': [.01, .02, .03, -.4, -.06, -.02, 
                             .06, .8, .9, .4, -1.06, .03],
            })


    returns["snail_chart_dates"] = ""
```

**example desired result - without middle**

[image]

Comment: What's the logic of finding the `middle` value date per group?

Comment: i think it would be something like ```.iloc[[0,len(df)/2,-1]]``` but again this would need a group by in the len part, i'm happy to attempt this later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we get the `min` and `max` date per group.

Then we get the indices of these values per group with `idxmin` and `idxmax`.

To get the middle values we get the `median` of the index per group and `round up` with `np.ceil`

And finally we assign these values to our new column with `loc`:

```
grp = returns.groupby('code_id')
s1 = grp['value_date'].transform('min')
s2 = grp['value_date'].transform('max')
s3 = grp.apply(lambda x: np.ceil(np.median(x.index))).values

idx_min = grp['value_date'].idxmin().values
idx_max = grp['value_date'].idxmax().values

returns.loc[idx_min, 'snail_chart_dates'] = s1.loc[idx_min]
returns.loc[idx_max, 'snail_chart_dates'] = s2.loc[idx_max]
returns.loc[s3, 'snail_chart_dates'] = returns.loc[s3, 'value_date']

   value_date code_id  gross_return  bm_return snail_chart_dates
0  2018-01-31     AUD          0.01       0.01        2018-01-31
1  2018-02-28     AUD          0.02       0.02               NaT
2  2018-03-31     AUD          0.03       0.03               NaT
3  2018-04-30     AUD         -0.40      -0.40        2018-04-30
4  2018-05-31     AUD         -0.06      -0.06               NaT
5  2018-06-30     AUD         -0.02      -0.02        2018-06-30
6  2018-01-31     USD          0.06       0.06        2018-01-31
7  2018-02-28     USD          0.80       0.80               NaT
8  2018-03-31     USD          0.90       0.90               NaT
9  2018-04-30     USD          0.40       0.40        2018-04-30
10 2018-05-31     USD         -1.06      -1.06               NaT
11 2018-06-30     USD          0.03       0.03        2018-06-30
```

Comment: You're welcome. Yes these are all vectorized methods except for `s3`, this should run quite fast, even for large data sets. @RachOdwyer

Comment: hmmm just getting a ValueError on ```idx_min = grp['value_date'].idxmin().values``` using pandas==0.23.4

Comment: File "C:Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 851, in wrapper
    raise ValueError

ValueError

Comment: You're copy and pasting the wrong part of the error. At the bottom where the `valueError` is, there's a more descriptive error message

Comment: interesting converting value_date to_datetime allows the code to run through

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you put `value_date` into the Pandas datetime format, there is a very simple solution.

We can group by the code, and use the `.quantile()` function to get our dates.

```
returns["value_date"] = pd.to_datetime(returns["value_date"])
code_groups = returns.groupby("code_id")["value_date"]
code_groups.quantile(0, interpolation="nearest")
```

```
code_id
AUD   2018-01-31
USD   2018-01-31
Name: value_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

```
code_groups.quantile(0.5, interpolation="nearest")
```

```
code_id
AUD   2018-03-31
USD   2018-03-31
Name: value_date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You can then assign this information as you wish into your table.